# newbie question about pointer to stl

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector

I have written this function

```
vector<long int>* randIntSequence(long int n) {
    vector<long int> *buffer = new vector<long int>(n, 0);
    for(long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        buffer->at(i);

    long int j; MTRand myrand;
    for(long int i = buffer->size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        j = myrand.randInt(i);
        swap(buffer[i], buffer[j]);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

but when I call it from main, myvec = randIntSequence(10), I see the myvector always empty. Shall I modify the return value?

Comment: One shouldn't allocate standard containers with `new` -- that sort of defeats the point! Also, your first `for` loop is a no-op.

Comment: This design seems suspect.  Why are you allocating the `vector` dynamically?  Is there a particular reason you aren't just creating it on the stack and returning it?  Can the random number generator throw exceptions?  Have you considered using a smart pointer?

Comment: yes, I forgot to assign i to the i-th element of buffer. My problem without pointers is this: if I want to remove the vector at some point, outside the function, will it be removed entirely?

Comment: Sounds like you should use `std::random_shuffle` instead then.

Comment: You need to push something on the vector, using [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/).

Answer (score 5):

The `swap` call is indexing the `*buffer` pointer as if it were an array and is swapping around pointers. You mean to swap around the items of the vector. Try this modification:

```
swap((*buffer)[i], (*buffer)[j]);
```

Secondary to that, your `at` calls don't set the values as you expect. You are pulling out the items in the vector but not setting them to anything. Try one of these statements:

```
buffer->at(i) = i;
(*buffer)[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 4):

You never assign to any of the elements in the `vector` pointed to by `buffer`:

```
for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    buffer->at(i); // do you mean to assign something here?
```

You end up with the `vector` containing `n` zeroes.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comment? Since you never quite answer the question, but answer with a question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has already been answered, so I'll make this CW, but this is how your code should look.

```
std::vector<long int> randIntSequence(long int n)
{
    std::vector<long int> buffer(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        buffer[i] = i;
    std::random_shuffle(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
    return buffer;
}
```

There is absolutely no reason you should be using a pointer here.  And unless you have some more advanced method of random shuffling, you should be using [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/).  You might also consider using [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) to initialize the vector:

```
std::vector<long int> buffer(
    boost::counting_iterator<long int>(0),
    boost::counting_iterator<long int>(n));
```

Though that may be overkill.

Comment: If your compiler has C++0x support, the initialization `for()` loop can be replaced with `std::iota(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 0);`

Comment: @Blastfurnace -- Cool, I didn't know about that function.  I have trouble recommending boost::counting_iterator because it's so unwieldy, but iota is much more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is about STL, and all you want is a vector with random entries then:

```
std::vector<long int> v(10);
generate( v.begin(), v.end(), std::rand ); // range is [0,RAND_MAX]

// or if you provide long int MTRand::operator()()  
generate( v.begin(), v.end(), MTRand() );
```

But if you want to fix your function then

- `n` should be `size_t` not `long int`
- First loop is no-op
- As John is saying, `buffer` is a pointer, so `buffer[0]` is your vector, and `buffer[i]` for `i!=0` is garbage. It seems you have been very lucky to get a zero-sized vector back instead of a corrupt one!
- Is your intention to do random shuffle? If yes, you are shuffling around zeros. If you just want to generate random entries then why don't you just loop the vector (from 0 to buffer->size(), not the other way around!!) and assign your random number?

C++ is not garbage collected, and you probably don't want smart pointers for such simple stuff, so you'll be sure to end up with leaks. If the reason is in generating a heap vector and returning by pointer is avoiding a copy for performance's sake, then my advise is don't do it! The following is the (almost) perfect alternative, both for clarity and for performance:

```
vector<T> randIntSequence( size_t n ) { 
   vector<T> buffer(n);
   // bla-bla
   return buffer; 
}
```

If you think there is excess copying around in here, read [this](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value) and trust your compiler.

Comment: Sorry for repeating others' comments here. I didn't realize your were commented upon until I posted the answer.